# TradingView Search Stock Functionality

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stock, tradingview-api

Is there any way that I could include the search symbol feature from TradingView into my nextjs project? I browsed through their widgets and could not find what I wanted.

Attached below is an example. I just want the symbol search feature and nothing else.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQuAJ.jpg)